# Is it Wise to Spend Cash on a C++ Book Keeping in View the Upcoming C++0x?

Tags: c++, c++11

I just purchased *C++ GUI Programming with Qt4* and after reading the code samples in this book I'm beginning to realize that my knowledge of C++ is incomplete. I learned C++ two years ago from online tutorials and a couple of ebooks I downloaded, and it turns out none of these resources were good enough. Since then I haven't touched the language and have been using Python instead.

Now I'm thinking of purchasing a good book on C++ that covers advanced topics, and the one I have in mind is Bruce Eckel's *Thinking in C++* (both volumes). I know they are available for free on the web, but I really can't stand reading books on a laptop screen.

Since C++0x might be out pretty soon, is it wise to go ahead and spend cash on these books? Will C++0x break backwards compatibility? Volume 2 covers features like multithreading, templates etc. Would any of these features change significantly in C++0x?

Comment: FYI, I read most of the first Eckels book in a week and found it extremely dull.  Stroustrup's book is far more interesting, and it starts out at a fairly basic level if you can get past the language flyby at the beginning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wouldn't hold my breath for C++0x.  I doubt it will be out by the end of this decade.  Even when it will be out, you should probably count a year or so for compilers to implement it.  Learn the fundamentals now, and it should be relatively easy for you to learn most of the new features when the standard is out.  The Standards Committee is known for its efforts to maintain backward compatibility.

I personally check with the evolution of the standard from time to time, just out of curiosity.  Subscribe to Herb Sutter's [blog](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/) [feed](http://herbsutter.wordpress.com/feed/) and look for Standard updates.

My personal favourite advanced C++ book is Bjarne Stroustrup's The C++ Programming Language, 3e.  It is the one single C++ book from which I think I learnt the most, with respect to language and STL details.  Scott Meyers' books helped clarify a lot of things too.  Meyers writes in a very readable language (English, I believe), and often what would happen is that I'd read an entire Item from Meyers' book, and then find the same information in Stroustrup's book condensed into a single sentence or so.  That is to say Meyers' books are extremely useful in getting your attention to interesting details.

As for the changes I expect for threading, I think there going to be two new libraries for this purpose in the standard.  Concepts are an even bigger change coming, and they are somewhat related to templates.  Up until now we had concepts in the STL, but these were *conventions*;  an algorithm would make assumptions about a type you pass to a template, and you'd know to pass the correct "type of type" because of the conventions.  This implied terribly error messages, the STL template errors we all know and "love".  Concepts will help solve these.  There are other improvements (complexities) to the language.  Herb Sutter talks about them a lot.

Comment: Notice that some compilers (gcc for example) already includes some c++0x features and are including more to get up to date as fast as possible. But you're right, it will not be "complete" and really interesting until maybe 2 years.

Comment: @Klaim, 3 years later, and it's still the same way!

Comment: Yeah, looks like GCC will need maybe two more years to get all the features... some of wich might take even more. I'm follwing the advances on the CLang compiler because they get faster to implement new things as the code is more flexible than GCC. But the problem is they did start implementing C++0x features only in the end of the last year...

Answer (score 7):

It is certainly wise to buy the book. C++1x will hardly break with previous code. Nearly everything you learn is also possible with the next C++, and it will greatly help you understand the need of *why* C++1x will introduce what feature. For example, why will it have *variadic templates*, and why those *concepts*?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the backward compatibility is broken on some features, the biggest part should be still usefull.

Furthermore, the first books on C++Ox might not be the best ones.

I would prefer a very good book on C++ to a book on C++Ox.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely go for buying the books

1. Those from Eckel are really good books, and I really recommend them.
2. It will take several years for compilers to catch up with new features introduced with  C++0x (just look how was with template support!)
3. It will take even more years for projects to start using them
4. Finally, although I do not know with detail the3 changes introduced with the new release of the language, the C++ committee has always been very conservative on backward compatibility, therefore you should do not have any risk of learning something will be obsolete soon.

Answer (score 1):

I'd echo the recommendation to get the Bjarne Stroustrup book "The C++ Programming Language
(Third Edition and Special Edition)" http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html in addition to any other book you may be interested in, if you can afford multiple books. If you can afford only one and have mastered the basics (as you have) then I'd probably learn towards the Stroustrup book. You can't go past getting the facts from the man himself.

You can track developments in C++0x here:
http://www.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html
if you are interested. As previously commented, I wouldn't hold my breath if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

You might try a site like Safari Books Online to keep up-to-date with technical and programming books.  I've bought several Ruby- and Ruby on Rails-related books in the past and they're now much less useful because the stuff in them is deprecated.

Comment: Ruby and Ruby-on-Rails are both churning much more heavily than C++.  Some of my most useful C++ books are over 8 years old, and they will continue to be useful with C++0x, because they are about language fundamentals, not library features.